# UNIX "No such file or directory" though I see it

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I feel as if there is a simple solution for this, but I myself am not able to figure it out. 
    Adams-MacBook-Pro-3:Random adam$ ls /Users/adamgoetsch/Documents/Java Workspace/
ls: /Users/adam/Documents/Java: No such file or directory
ls: Workspace/: No such file or directory

I am not able to list what is in this folder. It seems as if it is seeing /Users/adam/Documents/Java and Workspace/ as something separate. Some insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the space in `Java Workspace`, the terminal is treating  `/Users/adamgoetsch/Documents/Java` and `Workspace/` as two separate arguments to ls

To treat it as one path, either escape the space:

```
 ls /Users/adamgoetsch/Documents/Java\ Workspace/
```

Or put the path in quotes:

```
 ls '/Users/adamgoetsch/Documents/Java Workspace/'
```